# Build a Chrome Packaged Application in WebStorm 8

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-editor, google-chrome-app

I would like to switch from Dart Editor to WebStorm 8. But I am not able to compile my project as a Chrome Packaged App. I can simply run the HTML Files, which are completely ignoring my manifest.json and all chrome specific libs I'd like to use.

Can anyone give me suggestions how to add such a run configuration? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about building or debugging your chrome app?

AFAIK, you don't need to compile anything to **debug** your dart chome app. 
You just have to create the right [**manifest.json** and its **background.js**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) file to create the window/service.

If so, you can load your project directory directly in dartium by using the [load unpacked app feature](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked) or by using [the official chrome app developper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-developer-too/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc).

If your *manifest.json* and *background.js* are fine, your app ll show up in a dedicated window.

Then, you just have to do a ***right click* + *refresh the application*** inside the chrome app window to apply the code changes.

It completely works for debugging, but i never tried to build a release from WebStorm...